# To calculate Date before two working days if not working day then increase

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to calculate date before two days based on the condition .

Example  date = '2012-09-01' then @date should be '2012-08-30' but here if 2012-08-31 is not working day then @date should be '2012-08-29'.

Could you please help me on this

Comment: are you considering holidays?

Comment: Do you have a calendar table or at least a list of working days or non-working days?

Comment: yes I have list of working days.If work day count = 1 then it is calculated as working day otherwise non-working day....I need condition ...

Comment: I have table tbl_date where i have dates in one column and WorkdayCount in one column..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question though apparently seems to be simple, but not so as there are many test cases involved in it (at least I have interpreted in that way). Let me first write the query (I assume you are using Sql Server 2005+)

```
Declare @tbl_Data Table(Dates Date,WorkDayCount Int)

Insert Into @tbl_Data Select '2012-08-25',1
Insert Into @tbl_Data Select '2012-08-26',1
Insert Into @tbl_Data Select '2012-08-27',1
Insert Into @tbl_Data Select '2012-08-28',1
Insert Into @tbl_Data Select '2012-08-29',1
Insert Into @tbl_Data Select '2012-08-30',1
Insert Into @tbl_Data Select '2012-08-31',0
Insert Into @tbl_Data Select '2012-09-01',1

Declare @InputData Date = '2012-09-01'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Sequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Dates DESC),*
    FROM @tbl_Data
    WHERE  Dates < @InputData
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT 
        Sequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Dates DESC)
        ,Dates 
        ,WorkDayCount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Sequence  = ((SELECT TOP 1 Sequence FROM CTE WHERE WorkDayCount = 1)-1)
        UNION  
        SELECT TOP 2 * FROM CTE WHERE WorkDayCount = 1
    )X
)
SELECT TOP 1
            Date = CASE WHEN  Sequence = 1 AND  WorkDayCount = 0 THEN (SELECT Dates FROM CTE2 WHERE  Sequence = 3)
                    WHEN  Sequence = 1 AND  WorkDayCount = 1 THEN (SELECT Dates FROM CTE2 WHERE  Sequence = 2)
            END 
FROM CTE2
```

**CASE 1:Input date is 1st Sept(2012-09-01) and the immediate previous date's WorkDayCount = 0**

**Result:** `2012-08-29`

Reason: Since August 31st's WorkDayCount = 0, so the working date will be 29th August

**CASE 2: Input date is 1st Sept(2012-09-01) and the August 31st + August 30th WorkCount  = 0.**

**Result:** `2012-08-28`

**CASE 3:Input date is 1st Sept(2012-09-01) and the immediate previous date's WorkDayCount = 1**

**Result:** `2012-08-30`

Kindly correct me if any of the assumptions/test cases are incorrect.

Let me know your concern.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT MIN(DATE_COL) 
FROM  (
        SELECT  TOP 2  DATE_COL 
        FROM TBL_DATE
        WHERE DATE_COL<='2012-09-01'
        AND WORKDAYCOUNT =1)A
```